# How can IE10 send thousands of ajax post requests to my servlet within 60 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Today on my production server I got 1500 servlet posts (exact same request) within 60 seconds from someone working in their browser. Is it possible that the browser is not getting a success/return message and continually trying to re-post the message? This code has been running without issue for nearly two years. I have ruled out the possibility that it was done programmatically by the code. Any ideas at all about what could cause this would be very appreciated. Here is the code that sends the ajax request.

```
function buttonPressed(submissionType, updatePrice){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/requestHandlerJS",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        data: UTIL.serializeXML(xmlFromOrderHtml(submissionType, updatePrice)),
        success: function(xmlret) {
            var order = $(xmlret).find("order");
            if ($(xmlret).find("success").text() == "full") {
                _manuallyEditedPrice = false;
                if(order.attr("deleted") == 'true'){
                    UTIL.showSuccess("Order deleted");
                    window.location = '/ordersummary.jsp';
                } else if (order.attr("created") == 'true') {
                    UTIL.showSuccess("Order Saved");
                    _workingOrderId = order.attr("orderId");
                    _workingOrderGrouping = order.attr("grouping") == "grouped";
                    displayOrder(xmlret);
                    var newTitle = "Edit Order";
                    $("#titleli").html(newTitle);
                    $("#titleh1").html(newTitle);
                    document.title=newTitle;
                } else if (order.attr("updated") == 'true') {
                    UTIL.showSuccess("Order Saved");
                    drawButtons(order.find("submission-type"));
                }
            } else {
                UTIL.showComsatError(xmlret);
            }
            loadOrder(_workingOrderId, _workingOrderGrouping);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, msg, errorThrown) {
            UTIL.showError("xhr.status="+jqXHR.status+" error="+msg+" exception="+errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We can't really tell unless you put in the post the name of the function this code resides in, or the definition of any (or all) of the functions you are calling in the callbacks, or the location which this script resides.

Comment: we once had a similar issue that was caused by a redirect going wild / ending in a endless loop because the application servler had problems assigning a session cookie. In our scenario this caused 160,000 calls because the user left the browser open until the server exploded ... We also had this problem when a frustrated user kept the F5 down, but normally this only causes a few requests per second and not 25 like in yours.

Comment: How is the Ajax call being triggered?

Comment: They don't call it Internet Exploder for nothing...

Comment: Also 1500 seems a little high with the max request limit of 8 at a time. Talking 3+ requests per connection a second?

Comment: The code is just called from a button click. There is no other logic which could loop. I will update the snippet to reflect that.